# Recreating TD functions in normal SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I’ve been using rank(), row_number() and dense_rank() in Teradata SQL for quite sometime and have had to transition across to an older version of SQL, without these functions.

Is there a way to recreate these functions easily? I’m currently using a *proc sql;* in SAS-EG. I’m aware of SAS being able to use first. and last function but there must be a way to do it solely in SQL?

I’m aware of the monontonic() function but have yet to be able to reset it where I want my partition to end/able to create a dense_rank with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: (1) What database are you using?  Most databases support window functions.  (2) Why is your question tagged MySQL as well as Teradata?

Comment: What version? If you Google for converting window functions in MySQL 5 and lower, you should find plenty of examples of how to replicate real window functions. Plus, there's also MariaDB, if cost was a factor in having to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

`RANK`, `ROW_NUMBER` and `DENSE_RANK` are all [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) in MySQL-8.0. Just update to this version and they will be there.